# Multiplicity of primes in factorial

Tags: number-theory

> Denote by $x_n(p)$ the multiplicity of the prime $p$ in the canonical representation of the number $n!$ as a product of primes. Prove that $\dfrac{x_n(p)}{n} < \dfrac{1}{p-1}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{x_n(p)}{n} = \dfrac{1}{p-1}$.

**Attempt:**

The Legendre function gives us $x_n(p) = \sum_{i \geq 1} \left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{p^i}\right \rfloor$ and since $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor \leq x$, we have that $$\dfrac{x_n(p)}{n} < \dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{p^2}+\cdots = \dfrac{1}{p-1}.$$

How do we show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{x_n(p)}{n} = \dfrac{1}{p-1}$?

Comment: By the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), the representation of a number as the product of primes is unique; thus there's no such thing as a "canonical" representation as a product of primes.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x-\lfloor x\rfloor\lt1$,

\begin{align}
\frac1{p-1}-\frac{x_n(p)}n
&=\frac1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac n{p^i}-\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\log_p n\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac n{p^i}\right\rfloor\right)
\\
&\lt\frac{\lfloor\log_p n\rfloor}n+\sum_{i=\lceil\log_p n\rceil}^\infty\frac1{p^i}
\\
&=\frac{\lfloor\log_p n\rfloor}n+\frac{p^{-\lfloor\log_p n\rfloor}}{p-1}
\\
&\to_{n\to\infty}0\;.
\end{align}